# Establish Archimedean property of a vector-lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, lattice-orders, vector-lattices, banach-lattices

I am trying to find ways to prove the Archimedian property of a certain vector lattice and got stuck on the following type of problem.

I feel the statement below (or in fact weaker versions) should be provable, but I am not being very successful so far. I am posting this question here to get suggestions and/or counterexamples, thanks!

**Statement:** Let $A$ be a vector lattice ([wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space)) and let $B\subseteq A$ a subset of $A$ which:

1) B is closed under vector spaces operations (of $A$), i.e.: (i) if $b_1,b_2\in B$ then $b_1 +  b_2 \in B$, and (ii) if $b\in B$ then $r b\in B$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $B$ is a partially orderd vector subspace of $A$, but $B$ is not necessarily a lattice.

2) $B$ generates $A$, i.e., every element $a\in A$ is expressible as a finite combination of meet and joins from $B$: $a = \bigvee_i \bigwedge_j b_{i,j}$.

3) $B$ is Archimedean, in the sense that it does not have infinitesimals (except $0$): for all $b,b^\prime\geq0$ in $B$, if for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds that $nb \leq b^\prime$,  then $b=0$.

Under these assumptions it follows that $A$ is Archimedean as a vector lattice. I.e., for all $a,a^\prime\geq0$ in $A$, if for all $n$, $n a \leq a^\prime$  then $a=0$.

**end of Statement**

As I said, I have not been able to prove this so far. Perhaps there is some counterexample?

Comment: Do you have an example motivating this question?

Comment: Any examples would need to be infinite dimensional (see https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/MasterJongen.pdf). Also, since you’d have to a finite combination of meets and joins of elements of $B$ to produce any elements of $A$, it seems unlikely that there are any finite proper subsets $B$ that satisfy (2).